# How to make a button reset to default state?

Tags: swift, uibutton, switch-statement

I have a button that has 2 switch statements.

```
buttonPressed() {
 switch 1
 switch 2
}
```

Switch 1 checks for errors.  If no errors are found, Switch 2 executes.  This part works great.

The problem is, when an error is found, on the second press of the button, switch 1 is skipped.

How do I make the button always execute from the start every time it is pressed?

It's as if it creates a breakpoint at the end of the switch, and the second press continues from that breakpoint.

Here's an excerpt of the switch1:

```
case 1:
    let oneLength = countElements(textOne.text)
    if oneLength <= 1 {
        self.shouldSave = false
        showAlertWithText(message: "First checklist item must have a value")
    } else if oneLength >= 141 {
        self.shouldSave = false
        showAlertWithText(message: "First checklist item exceeds the 140 character limit")
    } else {
        newChecklistOne["goalID"] = self.dependantGoalID
        newChecklistOne["itemDescription"] = textOne.text
        newChecklistOne["isComplete"] = false
    }
```

switch 2 example:

```
if self.shouldSave == true {
while self.saveVarTwo <= self.z {
    switch self.saveVarTwo {
        case 1: newChecklistOne.saveInBackground()
```

Here's the showAlertWithText function:

```
func showAlertWithText (header : String = "Ermahgerd!!!", message : String) {
    var alert = UIAlertController(title: header, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

So, how do I make the button start executing code from line 1 on every button click?

Comment: if self.shouldSave == true { .. } is redundant. You should use  if shouldSave  { ... }

Comment: how is it redundant?  The default state is to set it as true.  Then, if an error is found, I have it changed to False.  That bool toggle then determines if switch 2 executes...

Comment: if shouldSave { ... } if you want to test if not just add ! at the front if !shouldSave { ... }

Comment: But how does that solve the problem?  I'm looking to have the button start from line 1 of the button function code each time the button is pressed.  Right now, it skips straight to switch2.  The shouldSave is working properly.

Comment: Thats why I've posted it as a comment. Just keep that in mind. that's all.

Comment: ahh gotcha.  Still new to coding and stack overflow.  Thank you for trying :)

Answer (score 0):

So, I had a "saveVar" that worked as the switch catalyst for switch 1.  It would iterate to the # of entries, but I never reset it when an error occurred.  Therefore, when the button was pressed, the switch started at the max case.